# Ubuntu GNOME live usb behaves radomly

Tags: boot, gnome, uefi, live-usb, 17.04

### Problem

Hi, I bought a new laptop and I would like to install Ubuntu GNOME since I read that is the best distro for 2 in 1 laptops ( if I'm wrong tell me, advice are very well accepted since I do not know the world of linux distros in depth).
By the way I downloaded the latest release of gnome and I created a live usb with Rufus.
The problem is that when I try to launch the live usb there are 3 different behaviours:

- The system **freeze** in the loading screen
- The system boots but **some icons are missing** and after some times I am
  prompted to a **login screen loop** and after I try to login for two times a
  black screen appears saying:

> a start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up ( 21s/no limit)

### Possible cause found

Today I tested the installation of **Ubuntu 17.10** and everything worked swiftly until **the OS showed the live USB as a storage unit**, after that I couldn't open any kind of app.
I think that this could be the problem since it happened on Ubuntu GNOME either, so **does anyone know why the live usb is seen from the OS as a simple memory stick?**

### Verified things and already tried solutions

- Since I have a desktop pc I tried the usb there end everything works without
  any sort of problem.
- I tried using **Ubuntu but the problem persists**
- I have disabled secure boot but the behaviour is still the same.
- I have changed the partition scheme in rufus from  MBR for Bios and UEFI to
  GPT for UEFI and I installed tha image as a DD image and that solved the
  problem of missing icons but not the login loop.

### Computer Specs

The computer I'm trying to install Ubuntu GNOME on is a lenovo yoga 520 with this specs:

- CPU: Intel core i5-7200U
- 8 gb RAM DDR4
- 1 TB HDD
- GPU: Intel HD graphics 7200

Thank you very much for reading, and sorry if my English isn't a hundred percent correct but I'm not a native speaker.
Good evening.